# MySQL Query to Read Out Data in IP Blocks?

Tags: mysql, sql, networking

I have a bunch of data stored in a MySQL database with a column called 'ip', and each record in the IP table is an IPv4 address that has been INET_ATON'd.

Example:

[image]

I'd now like to read out data with a where clause that matches any record such that the IP resolves to something in this range:

10.0.0.0 - 10.0.255.255

Any ideas on how to tackle this?

Comment: Do you have any idea for each column how many digits belong to each octet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Select * from table where ip>=inet_Aton('10.0.0.0') and ip<=inet_aton('10.0.255.255')
```

Comment: I was just about to post something similar, but ... yes - basically that is the solution.